# OnChange event fire even on same item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The default behavior for HTML `select` is when the item in the select changes, it would fire a  `onchange` event. However, let's say I have 3 items:

```
A
B
C
```

Now when the page loads in browser, A would be visible. I want that when A is again selected, the onchange should fire. How is that possible?

Comment: onchange will not fire when the value doesn't change. What are you trying to do? Maybe we can offer a better solution.

Comment: @Kevin: Please read my comments to Gabby

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
 if($("#element").val()==="A"){
    $("#element").trigger("change");
    }
```

Comment: this will not trigger unless the `value` in the `select` changes. So you'll stil need `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

just trigger it if you want its action to apply when loading the page

```
$(function(){
   $('yourselect').change();
});
```

Comment: This won't work. Basically I am preparing a mobile website and my navigation links are inside select. So, when I am on home page, the dropdown would show selected item as Home. So I want that again when user selects *Home* in select, the page should refresh itself again. Any way to achieve that?